# Embed Flash to Work with IOS as Well

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, flash

I want to ask that how could we embed a flash banner so that it should work with IOS as well. Currently I'm using this code, but want to change it so that it should work with IOS as well.

```
 <td height="244"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="158" height="244">
          <param name="movie" value="images/image_left.swf">
          <param name="quality" value="high">
          <embed src="images/image_left.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="158" height="244"></embed></object></td>
```

Comment: @j08691 is right. You might wanna declare some alternative for the iOS devices.

Comment: Flash is dead (well, dead for iOS, which means it's pretty much dead for things like web and add banners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently **no opportunity** to use Flash on iOS. Come back in 2 years with this question, may be there would be a solution.

Comment: So, should I convert it to gif.

Comment: Given that Adobe has stopped work on the Flash player for mobile browsers overall, I doubt Flash will make a resurgence in 2 years (for web use).

Answer (score 6):

Flash doesn't work on any iOS device.

Check out Steve Jobs' letter about this at http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/

Comment: Should I convert it to GIF then.

Comment: A GIF would work - but only for a completely non-interactive banner; note also that the resulting image could be HUGE in size.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, Flash will most likely never be implemented into iOS devices, however you could use a program such as Adobe Wallaby that converts flash files into an HTML animation. I've played around briefly with it and it seems to work rather well. Keep in mind that it is an "experimental technology". Here's the link http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/.